# (R) - Check if substring is contained in larger string and change value

Tags: r, substring, grepl, stringi

I am attempting to check a column in my dataset that is all character values with values like: "1","2","12","NAME1","NAME2",...

I am attempting to pick out the values that have non-numeric names and change them to 99.  This is what I have attempted so far:

```
install.packages("stringi")
library(stringi)
stacked_data$NewCol=ifelse(stri_detect_fixed(stacked_data$OldCol,"NAME")==TRUE,99,stacked_data)
```

I get this error message when I run this code:

```
Error in table(stacked_data$NewCol) : 
attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements
```

Can someone help point me in the right direction?  Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easier option is

```
  i1 <- is.na(as.numeric(df1$col))
  df1$col[i1] <- 99
```